# PRTG- Deploy remote probe to remote network

Tags: remote, amazon-web-services, wan

I would like to monitor a remote network, which I have permission to do so.  The PRTG Core would be in AWS (80.80.80.23 example) and I would deploy the PRTG remote probe to a remote network (40.40.40.23). There are no VPN connections. I can open up ports on the AWS side and I can manually deploy the remote probe the remote network.

Is this possible and how? All documentation I see state remote probe needs to deployed on LAN. If not on LAN cluster needs to be enabled. However  I do not need a cluster. Also cluster is disabled . Not to sure how I enable? Anycase, I need help please.

Answer (score 0):

If your core PRTG server(s) are clustered, then you will encounter the limitations associated with remote probes (that they don't take full advantage of cluster features), if not, that is if you have only one PRTG server  (no fault tolerance) then there is no special limitations regarding your case.

A remote probe best serve when it is responsible for a whole remote LAN, anyway it could still serve as a responsible for even a single node (no problem!). This means you will normally benefit from deploying a remote probe to a remote site that their nodes reach each other as LAN nodes such as easily allowing ICMP, SNMP, pings,etc between them.

Inspirations based on [this](https://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/7223-can-i-use-remote-probes-in-a-cluster-with-prtg#reply-18903) article.